# Unnest 2 levels - Big Query arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

Consider a BQ table with the following schema

```
name
day
day.purchase
```

And values

```
name     day              day.purchase
John    [1,2]  [ ['Coke', 'Fanta'], ['Pepsi', 'Fanta', 'Water'] ]
```

How to unnest both levels so I get the full table?

```
John 1 'Coke'
John 1 'Fanta'
John 2 'Pepsi'
John 2 'Fanta'
John 2 'Water'
```

Comment: The sample data and described data model do not match.

Comment: @Marc - presented schema and data sample do not match at all! even after you updated it - still looks quite wrong! i think you mean `day.id` instead of just `day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly getting your schema along with sample data - below is the way to go

```
select name, id as day, purchase
from yourtable t, t.day, day.purchase
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the described data model, you would just use:

```
select n.name, the_day, the_purchase
from names n cross join
     unnest(n.day) the_day cross join
     unnest(the_day.purchase) the_purchase;
```

For the data as shown, you have two separate columns, I think:

```
select n.name, day, purchase
from names n cross join
     unnest(n.days) day with offset nd join
     unnest(n.purchases) purchase with offset np
     on nd = np
```